# Defining arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multiple-definition-error

While defining variables at the start it fails to define the second 2d array. Why? How should it be done?

```
var NPC = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NPC[i] = new Array(7);
};

var previous_bead_NPC = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    previous_bead_NPC[i] = new Array(7);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean, it "fails to define the 2d array".  How can you tell?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the 2nd array. Did you get an error message while doing this or when you want to use these arrays?

Comment: In Firebug I can see only the NPC array and second one is absent.

Comment: I see both in Firefox/Firebug: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/AKZyD/

Comment: Still, in DOM tab in Firebug I only see NPC array. WTF I'm stupid or what?

Comment: Yes your code definitely defines both "NPC" and "previous_bead_NPC". What exactly is it that makes you think it isn't doing so?

Comment: See: http://i.imgur.com/FplTs.png It can be a little confusing, I suppose, in jsFiddle, since you have to find the `iframe`. It's there, though. Personally, I don't know why you're traipsing through the DOM tab to find your declared global arrays. Is there a root cause for you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no real point to using the Array constructor:

```
var NPC = [];
```

is fine. JavaScript doesn't preallocate space anyway (at least, modern runtimes don't). If you want an array to have a particular length, you can do this:

```
NPC[9] = undefined; // now it'll be 10 elements long
```

Thus if you want to make an array of 10 rows, each of which being an array of length 7:

```
var NPC = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  NPC[i] = [];
  NPC[i][6] = undefined;
}
```

(I don't know why you'd want that, but I guess it could serve some purpose.)

Comment: Old habits can be hard to break, I suppose.

Comment: What's the point of setting an element somewhere to undefined? Setting the length property (best at initialisation with the Array constructor) seems less confusing.

Comment: You know, you're right; I haven't had enough coffee this morning. :-) Well also I personally dislike the Array constructor because the semantics are so odd and inconsistent. This whole question is just kind-of pointless I think.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is what i see when i paste your code in a sample web site. No modifications made. So i guess your problem can be solved by fixing/updating your firebug ;)

Comment: I don't know why it did not list properly previous_bead_NPC - I changed it to Previous_bead_NPC and I can see it now just as you do. Stupidest thing ever.

Comment: Also in the jsFiddle demo: http://i.imgur.com/FplTs.png

Comment: @user1510009 no problem dude. I'll flag this question for a delete, because in the end there is no value in this question or it's answers.